# IIFE and Arrow Functions with setInterval plain JS

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, iife

I have the following code:

```js
window.setInterval((array => {
  console.log(array[0]++);
  console.log(array[1]++);
})([0, 0]), 500);
```

I expected that the code above would yield `0` and `0` each run (500ms). However, it doesn't. It only ran once. When I tried:

```js
window.setInterval((array => () => {
  console.log(array[0]++);
  console.log(array[1]++);
})([0, 0]), 500);
```

It worked. I thought that the first one will still print out `0` and `0` every 500ms as the IIFE with parameter `array` will always be given the values `[0, 0]` per run (however, this wasn't the case, it ran only once!). Then, the second code somehow allows `array` to "remember" its previous value and update its value per run. Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter passed to `setInterval` should be a function. In the first snippet, you're *invoking* a function immediately and returning `undefined`:

```
window.setInterval((array => {
  console.log(array[0]++);
  console.log(array[1]++);
})([0, 0]), 500);
```

is equivalent to

```
window.setInterval(() => {
  // do something, return undefined
})(), 500);
```

and once the IIFE is evaluated:

```
window.setInterval(undefined, 500);
```

So, you need something like your second snippet, in which the IIFE also returns a function:

```js
window.setInterval((array => () => {
  console.log(array[0]++);
  console.log(array[1]++);
})([0, 0]), 500);
```

Though, you might consider defining `array` inside the outer IIFE to make the code a bit clearer:

```js
window.setInterval(
  (() => {
    const array = [0, 0];
    return () => {
      console.log(array[0]++);
      console.log(array[1]++);
    };
  })(),
  500
);
```

Comment: Ah I see! Right, I need to pass a function expression inside `setInterval` instead of executing my function. So on my second snippet, I passed an IIFE expression which will be invoked later per 500ms, right?

Comment: Yep, the first snippet's function is being invoked immediately, and no more, while the second snippet's is being invoked after 500ms, 1000ms, etc.

Comment: More questions. So I'm using IIFE here to provide a lexical scope for my array which will not pollute the global scope whilst at the same time preventing access to my `array` variable from the "outside", right?

Comment: Yep - I just thought that if that's the goal, it would be clearer to define it inside the outer IIFE, rather than calling the outer IIFE with it.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I do agree that yours is easier to be understood.